# Wire installation

Tags: light, installation

I purchased a light pendant that has red, blue and yellow/green wiring. However, I’m looking to connect it to a black, white and ground wire. Do you know how to go about doing this?

Comment: Did ti come with a hook-up diagram? Which country is this in?

Comment: Where did you purchase the light from?  The wire colours for the light are UK/Europe colours, so that light might not be legal for use.  If so blue=white, red=black and green/yellow=ground.

Comment: What kind of bulb does it take? Did it come with a bulb? If it is a European/UK bulb, it would need 240 V rather than 120 V.

Comment: I think it is from China and had NO directions. It is a pendant with the light already included. This is my first time using this site but I’ll try attaching a photo

Answer (score 1):

In NZ, we follow the European scheme and

It used to be

- Green/Yellow - Earth
- Black - Neutral
- Red - Line/Phase

The current colours are

- Green/Yellow - Earth
- Blue - Neutral
- Brown - Line/Phase

We often get a mixture of colours, but **Blue/Black** is neutral and **Red/Brown** is Live.

There is a reference here at [nz.rs-online.com](https://nz.rs-online.com/web/content/discovery/ideas-and-advice/wiring-colours-guide)

I don't know the standard for USA, so I will leave that for someone else to complete.

Comment: Not sure if it matters for lights, but USA is also 120 volts on live wire.  Quite a few other places use 220-240 live wire.

Comment: Thank you. I’ll look into that!